# What do I need to do to "register" 'latexpdf' for Sphinx?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

When I run Sphinx using 'latexpdf' I get an error, even though I have a complete working TeX installation on my machine:

> Sphinx error: Builder name latexpdf not registered

What do I need to do to "register" `latexpdf`?

Answer (score 9):

**latexpdf** is not a Sphinx builder; it is the name of a target in the Makefile created by sphinx-quickstart. This target uses the **latex** builder.

Executing [`sphinx-build -b latexpdf . _build`](http://sphinx-doc.org/invocation.html) produces the error in the question (as expected).

If you run `make latexpdf`, it works.

---

PyCharm was mentioned in a comment and the problem seems to stem from that program. The following is run when latexpdf is configured as a "Command" ([Sphinx task](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-sphinx-task.html)):

```
sphinx_runner.py -b latexpdf <indir> <outdir>
```

The `sphinx_runner.py` script is very similar to `sphinx_build` (a wrapper for `sphinx.cmdline.main()`). Since the `-b` option is supposed provide the name of an actual builder, there is an error.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to look into what my IDE (PyCharm) is doing then. It offers `latexpdf` as a "command" for document building in a way tha takes them look like the IDE build UI is merely a wrapper for `make`; but perhaps it isn't.

Comment: Was this answer of any help to you?

Comment: Not sure. I'll have to go back and reconstruct the problem.

Comment: Using Pycharm 2016.1 which now uses sphinx_runner instead of sphinx-build I'm still getting: Builder name latexpdf not registered

Answer (score 7):

Use `-M` instead of `-b`.  This invokes `sphinx-build` similarly to `make latexpdf`, e.g.:

```
sphinx-build -M latexpdf . _build
```

See @mzjn's answer for details.

Comment: Yes, you do it in the dir containing the `conf.py` and `Makefile`.

Answer (score 3):

Now have Pycharm 2016.3 generating a pdf form me based on information here: https://www.quora.com/How-to-create-a-PDF-out-of-Sphinx-documentation-tool

Install rst2pdf:

```
pip install rst2pdf
```

Edit a new Python Docs sphinx configuration and choose pdf as the command.  Set input directory and directory to hold .pdf as output.

Edit the conf.py file and add the two lines that mention pdf:

```
 extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'rst2pdf.pdfbuilder'
]

pdf_documents = [('index', u'documentation', My Docs', u'Me'), ]
```

Now run the configuration and you should get a file called documentation.pdf in the output directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a pure Python solution, the following works for me:

```
import sphinx.cmd.make_mode as sphinx_build

OUT_DIR = "docs"  # here you have your conf.py etc
build_output = os.path.join(OUT_DIR, "_build")

# build HTML (same as `make html`)
build_html_args = ["html", OUT_DIR, build_output]
sphinx_build.run_make_mode(args=build_html_args)

# build PDF latex (same as `make latexpdf`)
build_pdf_args = ["latexpdf", OUT_DIR, build_output]
sphinx_build.run_make_mode(args=build_pdf_args)
```

In fact, I've made a [complete Python3 script](https://github.com/andres-fr/python3-template/blob/master/ci_scripts/make_sphinx_docs.py) that given a few convenient arguments generates the whole package documentation as HTML and PDF from scratch, with the RTD theme. It can be pretty handy if you want it to run it on different OS or Python interpreters (in my case i wanted to run it within Blender), or adapt it to your needs. It still has some dirty spots, due to some variables being hardcoded into `conf.py`. Let me know if you see any issues with it!

This is how it looks like:

- [HTML](https://python3-template.readthedocs.io)
- [PDF](https://github.com/andres-fr/python3-template/blob/master/docs/_build/latex/dummypackage.pdf)

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: i'm a little confused - sometimes `conf.py` seems to be in `docs`, sometimes in `docs/source`, is there a standard to this?

Comment: @baxx Sorry I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: In sphinx docs the conf.py file is found within two places (that I've seen), one is `./docs`, and the other is `./docs/source`. I'm not sure if there's a standard to this, but using the `sphinx-quickstart` puts it in `./docs/source` i think. The template that you've created looks helpful though, thanks

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I went straight to the pure python solution because I wanted to automate and integrate it with my other CI scripts. I don't know if I followed any convention to do that, so likely I didn't. Shouldn't be hard to alter the script, though. Let me know if you encounter any problem

Comment: yeah, as someone who's not as well versed in these things I suppose it's a little confusing for me which I should use. I'm currently trying to make some projects a bit more robust, and your example is very nice for that (thanks). But I fear if I use some of it there may be large clashes with sphinx as it seems to deviate from their defaults. Just a concern of mine, perhaps not one of yours. This may be off-topic for this thread, not sure if there's somewhere better, or if it's off-topic for yourself as well ha.